# time zone for kuwait country in magento

Tags: magento

In magento,what time zone I should set for kuwait country.Although I have set the Arab Standard Time (Asia/Riyadh) but there is 3 hours difference is showing.
In default magento, there is no time zone for kuwait country.
Please give me some idea how can I set the time zone for kuwait country or I have to do some manual functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The timezones `Asia/Riyadh` and `Asia/Kuwait` both are [UTC+03:00](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC+03:00), so *yes*, you can use Riyadh.

#### Why can't I find Kuwait (or some other missing) timezone in Magento?

This is because Magento only uses a subset of the [timezones supported by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). Taking Asia as an example, Magento only uses **30** of the around **90** asian timezones that PHP actually does support.

I can't tell why Magento decided to use subsets only, but most probably they just combined timezones having the same UTC offsets to make the timezone lists smaller and clearer.

Comment: Please post the code outputting a delayed value. We need to know where the value you're talking about is coming from (database/custom) and which method is being used to format it for output.